# Where do I ask about corporation sales?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, business

I currently work for Acxiom, which just sold 3/4 of itself to Interpublic Group. I am interested in finding out more about what motivates businesses to sell themselves. I can find websites left and right about why small businesses would want to sell themselves, but not larger ones.

Which Stack Exchange site should I ask this kind of question on? Personal Finance explicitely bars this kind of question, the next closest I can find is quantitative finance (but this question is more qualitative than quantitative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that there are over 150 Stack Exchange sites, there are still plenty of questions that aren't a good fit anywhere on the network. In some cases, that's because the question format doesn't work well in the SE Q&A model; in others, it's because there just aren't enough experts interested in the topic who have come together to launch a site.

For your question, I'd say it's both. If you're asking for the specific case of Acxiom, that can't really be answered except by anyone other than company executives, so you wouldn't get a good answer on SE—you'd get unverifiable enlightened speculation at best. If you're asking for the general case, your question is kinda discussion-y, not really Q&A. And in either case, there isn't currently a site where large business sales are in-scope.